# Can Jenkins build code to remote servers when triggered by GitHub webhook?

Tags: github, jenkins, ansible, continuous-deployment

I have a 'master' server (docker container actually) where I want to install Jenkins in order to link it (with webhook) with a github repo, so every time a developer pushes code, jenkins will auto-pull and build the code.

The thing is that there are an arbitrary number of extra 'slave' servers that need to have the exact same code as the master.

I am thinking of writing an Ansible playbook to be executed by Jenkins everytime the webhook runs and send the code to the slaves.

Can Jenkins do something like this?

Do I need to make the same setup to all the slaves with Jenkins and webhooks?

EDIT:

I want to run a locustio master server on the server that is going to have jenkins. My load tests are going to be pulled from Github there, but the same code needs to reside in the slaves in order to run in distributed mode.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow what you mean. It might be useful to add some more detail in to your set up such as explaining what services are running on what servers.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is that Jenkins certainly has the ability to run Ansible playbooks.  You can add a build-step to the project that is receiving the web hook that will run the playbook.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I know I can give Jenkins a script to run (Ansible playbook) after the build. I was wondering if I could do it all by Jenkins and not use Ansible at all.

Answer (score 0):

jenkins could trigger another job even on slaves. Then if i get correctly your issue , you just need something like that. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin

You could build your job by name trigger. Also there is another useful plugin called artifactory. This manages your packages and serves. This mean , you can build your code for once and share to slave and slaves could access your build and runs job.